# Logstash Error: "too many arguments" when attempting to start/run logstash

Tags: python, django, windows, elasticsearch, logstash

Was attempting to run logstash on my python/django project with the following command on windows (using git bash):

```
./logstash -f path/to/logstash.conf
```

I was getting this error

```
/c/Program Files/logstash-7.13.0/bin/logstash: line 40: cd: too many arguments
/c/Program Files/logstash-7.13.0/bin/logstash: line 40: /c/Users/Stephanie/Documents/Projects/BidRL/bidrl-reporting/bin/logstash.lib.sh: No such file or directory
/c/Program Files/logstash-7.13.0/bin/logstash: line 41: setup: command not found
/c/Program Files/logstash-7.13.0/bin/logstash: line 59: setup_classpath: command not found
/c/Program Files/logstash-7.13.0/bin/logstash: line 60: exec: : not found
```

I created a notion with every step I took to try to resolve the error.
Eventually I decided to try moving logstash from c/program files to c.
This solved the issue.

I cd into the logstash directory:

```
cd "/c/logstash-7.13.0/bin/"
```

And then run logstash

```
./logstash -f path/to/logstash.conf
```

This is the output

```
Using bundled JDK: /c/logstash-7.13.0/jdk
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in $LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using --path.settings. Continuing using the defaults
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path /C:/Program Files/logstash-7.13.0/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs errors to the console
[INFO ] 2021-05-25 14:34:41.276 [main] runner - Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.13.0", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.16.0 (2.5.7) 2021-03-03 f82228dc32 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.10+9 on 11.0.10+9 +indy +jit [mswin32-x86_64]"}
[WARN ] 2021-05-25 14:34:41.360 [LogStash::Runner] multilocal - Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[INFO ] 2021-05-25 14:34:41.602 [Agent thread] configpathloader - No config files found in path {:path=>"C:/logstash-7.13.0/bin/path/to/logstash.conf"}
[ERROR] 2021-05-25 14:34:41.608 [Agent thread] sourceloader - No configuration found in the configured sources.
[INFO ] 2021-05-25 14:34:41.755 [Api Webserver] agent - Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[INFO ] 2021-05-25 14:34:46.864 [LogStash::Runner] runner - Logstash shut down.
```

It's starting logstash but still has some errors.

Wanted to post this since there isn't much documentation on it.

[This](https://www.notion.so/Steps-I-m-taking-to-configure-elasticsearch-Stephanie-9cf0ee31a5224507840a7837cd153d4b#29a4115ef5294356aa7ad0e913b43b43) is one of the docs I found that was very helpful:

Answer (score 0):

Here is the notion with all the steps I took: https://www.notion.so/Steps-I-m-taking-to-configure-elasticsearch-Stephanie-9cf0ee31a5224507840a7837cd153d4b

Comment: The steps you listed in notion look slightly different to the ones in your question. Are you sure you've documented the question correctly? In the linked notion page, it looks like you call `$service` instead of just `service`. It would help if you describe the problem in a way that other can reproduce.